# How to retrieve metadata from Icecast 2.4.0 server

Tags: flutter, icecast2

I need to retrieve metadata from an online radio stream [text](https://servidor21.brlogic.com:7216/live). specifically the artist's name and song title for the "playing now" feature in my app. Postman shows in the response that the server is Icecast 2.4.0-kh9, and icy-metaint is set to 16000. I've consulted the documentation, and it states: :

> Icecast uses the very powerful libXSLT engine to transform its internal raw statistical data into custom tailored interfaces. Many people have written custom XSLT code that produces e.g. plain text “now playing”, XSPF, VCLT, munin interface data, etc. Since version 2.4.0 Icecast includes a basic JSON API (/status-json.xsl) based on a xml2json template by Doeke Zanstra (see xml2json.xslt). It exposes a basic set of server statistics that should fulfil basic user needs. The intention is to not break backwards compatibility of this interface in the future, still we recommend to design robust software that can deal with possible changes like addition or removal of variables.

I tried using the command `curl https://servidor21.brlogic.com:7216/live/status-json.xsl` with no luck. it returned "Could not parse XSLT." I am completely new to this and not sure if this metadata is even streamed. I tried ChatGPT 3.5 and it did not help either.  There is a chance that I am completely missing some important concept. Actually I build flutter online radio app as my first project and stuck. Any help is appreciated.